# How to transform an array of objects' keys and subkeys into a link to some property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array which includes some keys and subkeys of the object:

```
let keysArray = ['Computer Technics', 'Laptops', 'Lenovo', 'Ideapads',];
```

And also I have an object:

```
let obj = {
    'Computer Technics': {
        'Laptops': {
            'Lenovo': {
                'Ideapads': "data"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I need to get a link to the "data":

```
obj['Computer Technics']['Laptops']['Lenovo']['Ideapads']
```

I can't understand how to do that..

I mean I wrote a function which creates a link itself, but I have no idea how to connect it with **obj**

```
console.log(obj[getKey(keysArray)]); // obviously undefined as a result is put into '[]'
console.log(obj+getKey(keysArray)); //obviously it doesn't work too

function getKey(arr) {
    let res = '';
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res = res + '[\'' + arr[i] + '\']';
    }
    return res;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: `keysArray.reduce((a, k) => a[k], obj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
var pointer = obj;
for ( key of keysArray) { pointer = pointer[key]} ;
console.log(pointer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
let keysArray = ['Computer Technics', 'Laptops', 'Lenovo', 'Ideapads',];

let obj = {
    'Computer Technics': {
        'Laptops': {
            'Lenovo': {
                'Ideapads': "data"
            }
        }
    }
};

const value = keysArray.reduce((a, c) => a[c], obj);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: You can simplify it to: `keysArray.reduce((a, c) => a[c], obj)`

Comment: @adiga Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't realised that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object references

```js
let keysArray = ['Computer Technics', 'Laptops', 'Lenovo', 'Ideapads',];

let obj = {
    'Computer Technics': {
        'Laptops': {
            'Lenovo': {
                'Ideapads': "data"
            }
        }
    }
};

let getData = (arr,obj) => {
  let output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  arr.forEach(val => {
    output = output && output[val]
  })
  return output
}

console.log(getData(keysArray,obj))
```